# NANP phone numbers available for testing

Tags: phone-number, reserved

Wikipedia states that [555-01xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_%28telephone_number%29) are available for use in fictional works. Though this block of 100 numbers can presumably be stretched over all area codes, are there any larger blocks specifically reserved for testing/fictional/other usage, such as [example.com](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606), .test, [192.0.2.0/24](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330), or 10.0.0.0/8. For example, would testing be a valid use of the 700 area code (paralleling the 10.0.0.0/8 block)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible answer - NXX 958 and 959 are [reserved for testing](http://www.atis.org/inc/Docs/iss/iss245.doc) across all area codes, so using them for testing ideally should not be a problem, ie xxx-958-xxxx or xxx-959-xxxx.

Comment: Going to mark this accepted - using xxx-555-01xx should provide enough unique numbers for most reasonable testing, and they are reserved for works of fiction (such as test data).